# Use vba to copy value of cell to another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have been having no luck finding a simple vba script that writes the value of a specific cell to another cell. I found below code here, but it doesn't seem to function. What I really want to do is constantly put the value of cell G22 in cell F15.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G22")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("F15") = Range("G22")
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: write in cell `F15` formula `=G22`

Comment: Sadly that won't work as my sheet is set up in such a way that would cause a circular warning reference. This really cannot be easily solved without remaking big parts of the entire worksheet, so I am hoping this would be a excellent short term solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
Range("F15").Value = Range("G22")
```